# Is a Kohen required to marry a virgin?

Tags: halacha, marriage, kohen-priest

In a recent conversation with several friends regarding ba'alei teshuva marrying Kohanim (specifically college students), one person present said that a Kohen can only marry a virgin. I contested this point based on the first Aliyah of Parshat Emor.  Plus, I remember at least one explanation that said a regular Kohen can marry a widow, but cannot marry a divorcee.  However, that same person says the prohibition for a regular Kohen is derived from the Kohen Gadol.

So, is a regular Kohen allowed to marry a widow or is he - like the Kohen Gadol - required to only marry a virgin?

Comment: +1. Only a Kohen Gadol, IIRC. +1 to Avrohom Yitzchok's answer.

Comment: Although Avrohom Yitzchok is right in theory (and therefore +1), many rabbis will make regular exceptions for actual cases of kohanim.

Comment: In spite of all these answers suggesting that only the Kohen Gadol must marry a virgin, there is a pretty widespread (though secondary) opinion that this applies to all kohanim l'chatchila.

Comment: Strict people such as Satmar make them marry virgins, al pi posuk.

Comment: a kohen can marry widows and theyre not virgins... so no that can't be correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [this Chabad article](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/468267/jewish/Kohen-Marriages.htm) the restrictions on whom a Kohen can marry are:

> A kohen may not marry a ge’rusha (divorcee), chalalah (woman of
>   defective kohen status), zonah (woman who previously violated certain
>   sexual prohibitions), giyoret (convert) or chalutzah (a Levirate
>   widow). If he does marry any of them, their children likewise become
>   chalalim. Sons born do not have priestly status, and daughter may not
>   marry kohanim.

The categories are explained in more detail on the site. An ordinary kohen may marry a widow. Only the Kohen Gadol is forbidden to marry a widow because Hashem commanded so in the Torah.

Obviously CYLOR for a real case.

**ADDITION**
For @Zvi, who in the comment below asks for a non-Chabad source, this on [Marital defilement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Kohanic_disqualifications) is from Wikipedia.

> A male Kohen may not marry a divorcee, a prostitute, a convert, or a
>   dishonored woman (חללה) (Leviticus 21:7) A Kohen who enters into such
>   a marriage loses the entitlements of his priestly status while in that
>   marriage. The Kohen is not permitted to forgo his status and marry a
>   woman prohibited to him (Leviticus 21:6-7). However, in the event that
>   a Kohen transgresses a marital restriction, upon termination of the
>   marriage the Kohen is allowed to re-assume his function and duties as
>   a full Kohen.[citation needed]
>
> Modern-day kohanim are also prohibited from marrying a divorcee (even
>   their own divorced wife); a woman who has committed adultery, had been
>   involved in incest, or had relations with a non-Jew; a convert; or the
>   child of two converts. A born-Jewish woman who has had premarital
>   relations may marry a kohen only if all of her partners were Jewish.

[This at Jewish Answers.com](http://www.jewishanswers.org/ask-the-rabbi-1876/marriage-to-a-kohen/?p=1876) explains the “zona. prostitute” prohibition;

> “Zona” means a prostitute and refers to a Jewish woman who had sex
>   with a non-Jew. A Kohen is designated by G’d to serve Him in a more
>   intimate capacity that other Jews and, as such, he is required to
>   maintain a higher spiritual level. He is not required to marry a
>   virgin but he cannot marry a convert, a divorcee or a prostitute.

Comment: What is the reason for not marrying a convert? Couldn't some of the same issues be involved as a baal teshuva?

Comment: @Daniel There might be similar issues, but not necessarily.

Comment: @Daniel As I remember it, (male) kohanim can't marry (female) converts because we assume they've had sex since age 3 (or before, but before doesn't count).  We don't make that assumption about non-religious Jews.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman: But what if we know that to be the case about non-religious Jews? Isn't that exactly what this question is about?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I have heard talk about this issue; there may be routes to a solution in an individual case. That's why I included the CYLOR advice.

Comment: @Daniel, if a particular woman had relations before marriage, she may indeed be barred from marrying a _kohen_; as others have advised, they should contact their rabbi(s).

Comment: Can anyone provide me with Halachik sources other than a Chabad article?

Comment: @Zvi: The article is an excerpt from The Jewish Way in Love & Marriage by Rabbi Maurice Lamm. It is possible that the book itself has footnotes with sources.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I don't think we paskin like that opinion, and we forbid convertesses who converted even below the age of three, meaning (convert == zonah) just by definition, unrelated to other forms of zonah.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman AvrohomYizchok Daniel : See here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22496/759 for more about the precise definition of a Zonah.

Comment: There is an additional one that none of these sources mention: a Cohen cannot marry a woman with a non-Jewish father. (However, this marriage is permitted b'dieved.)

Answer (score 6):

An unmarried woman who had relations with a kosher Jew may marry a kohen ([Even Haezer 6:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.6.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and their children are kosher kohanim.
Here is the full text of the Shulchan Aruch with the relevant line in bold:

**שולחן ערוך אבן העזר הלכות פריה ורביה סימן ו סעיף ח**

> אי זו היא זונה, כל שאינה בת ישראל, או בת ישראל שנבעלה לאדם שהיא אסורה לינשא לו איסור השוה לכל, או שנבעלה לחלל אף על פי שהיא מותרת לינשא לו. לפיכך הנרבעת לבהמה, אף על פי שהיא בסקילה, לא נעשית זונה ולא נפסלה לכהונה, שהרי לא נבעלה לאדם. והבא על הנדה, אף על פי שהיא בכרת, לא נעשית זונה ולא נפסלה לכהונה, שהרי אינה אסורה לינשא לו. **וכן הבא על הפנויה, אפי' היתה קדשה שהפקירה עצמה שהיא במלקות, לא נעשית זונה ולא נפסלה מכהונה, שהרי אינה אסורה לינשא לו**. אבל הנבעלת לאחד מאיסורי לאוין השוין בכל ואינה מיוחדת בכהנים או מאיסורי עשה, וא"צ לומר למי שהיא אסורה לו משום ערוה, או לעובד כוכבים ועבד, הואיל והיא אסורה לינשא לו הרי זו זונה. וכן הגיורת והמשוחררת, אפילו נתגיירה ונשתחררה פחותה מבת שלש שנים, הואיל ואינה בת ישראל הרי זו זונה ואסורה לכהן. וכן יבמה שבא עליה זר, עשאה זונה. וי"א שהבא על חייבי עשה או על חייבי לאוין, אפילו חייבי לאוין דשאר, לא עשאה זונה, חוץ מהבא על היבמה.

Comment: Could you please post a link to the text?

Comment: edited to include full text

Answer (score 3):

I am a Sephardic Kohen by tradition and by genetics. I can trace my ancestry back 17 generations. By the traditions of my paternal ancestors and supported by Ezekial a Kohen, a Kohen should only marry a virgin. This is the fence around the law that many Sephardic Kohanim have placed upon themselves.  In the case of an older Kohanim past the age of normal child bearing he may follow the conventional outline as outlined by Chabad.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for sharing your tradition! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. You may be particularly interested in [our other questions about _kohanim_](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kohen-priest). If you don't mind, could you [edit] in to your answer where your family stems from? I know Persian and Moroccan Jews (for example) often have very different traditions.

Answer (score 2):

A Kohen cannot marry the people mentioned above. But that is only if he is 'still' a kohen and not himself a 'chollol'.
Many BT Kohanim are themselves challolim that would allow them to marry anybody.

Comment: This seems more like a comment on the question, as it doesn't actually address the question, which was about "regular kohanim".

Comment: @DoubleAA "regular Kohen" in the question is clearly meant in contrast to "the Kohen Gadol".

Comment: @msh210 and also clearly implies both the regular kohen and the kohen gadol are kohanim.

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes but I *think* in common speech a _chalal_ is called a _kohen_. (I'm really not sure, though.)

Comment: Many BT kohanim have this problem that they find it difficult to find anyone except another BT who could possibly be classified a zonah. If they were a chalal which is very possible it would help them.

Answer (score -3):

It is not permitted to change the words of the tora; not to add restrictions to the existing laws, nor to take restrictions away from tha law. I have in front of me Leviticus 21:6 and 21:14, the last sentence. All 21:13 and 21:14 only applies to the kohen gadol (who is an a position of having been anointed)

So, if you are not a virgin you may marry a kohen, but he can not become a kohen gadol, as long as you both are married.

They (the rabbis) speak about the kohan´s privileges: where are my privileges as long as the Jewish people are governed by the rabbis instead of the kohanim?

Comment: Just last month I gave a local kohein a sheep's jaw, maw, and paw. Your privileges are still quite available if you know where to find them.

Comment: @mikita, I am curious as to your source for the following assertion: "So, if you are [NOT] a virgin you may marry a kohen, but he can not become a kohen gadol, as long as you both are married." BTW I added the word NOT as it's missing.