# Would a violated woman be allowed to remain married to her Cohen husband?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, sexuality, divorce

As a continuation from my last question, [Would looking away help a Cohen stay Married to his wife?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53781/would-looking-away-help-a-cohen-stay-married-to-his-wife), would a raped woman be allowed to live with her Cohen husband?

Would there be room to allow them to live together but not to have relations (due to him being a Cohen)?
Can anyone quote a source on this?

Comment: you mean does yichud apply?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28268/what-happens-to-the-family-of-a-kohen-today-if-his-wife-is-a-victim-of-rape  - dupe?

Comment: Maybe like roah machmas tashmish?

Comment: @DoubleAA right. I am not sure why this question was closed, nowhere in its alleged duplicate is any source presented whether or not they may live together without having relations.

Comment: @ray perhaps. More so is there an Issur to remain married to her.

Comment: @Yehuda "can anyone quote sources" does not make this a different question - when the other question asked "Can divorce be avoided" that is implicitly asking for sources, as they obviously aren't interested in my opinion about staying married - it's a halachic question. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @YeZ if the other question wanted sources, why does the  unsourced answer have so many upvotes and no complaints from the mods about the lack of sources?

Comment: I recall reading in Responsa from the Holocaust by R' Ephraim Oshry that he allowed somebody whom the Nazis castrated (IIRC) to remain married - possibly with some caveats. That may be a place to start looking for sources.

Comment: @DannySchoemann very interesting, something to think about is that a castrated person wouldn't be able to transgress anyway so that may carry extra leniency. thanks

Comment: On page 99 R' Oshry could not find a way to allow a violated Mrs. Cohen to remain married to her husband - even though he always tries to be very lenient considering the unfortunate circumstances. (E.g. in this Q he refuses to take into account the possibility that a Mrs. Israel voluntarily submitted herself to the Nazi beasts and could possibly become forbidden to her husband.)

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better source for this but see אבן העזר סימן ז סעיף ט and there in the בית שמואל and the חלקת מחוקק that deal with this. It seems clear from there that they are forbidden to remain in the same house, even without Yichud.

Answer (score 0):

See Tosafos [Zevachim 2b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01033.html#HtmpReportNum0001_L2) s.v. S'tam who permit a woman in similar circumstances to remain married provided the couple do not have relations. Their words serve as a springboard for detailed in-depth discussion of this matter by the authorities who followed them.

> **סתם אשה לאו לגירושין עומדת**. ואפי' זינתה תחת בעלה מכל מקום לאו להתגרש בגט זה עומדת וגם אם לא ירצה הבעל לא יגרשנה **אלא שלא תשמשנו**

Comment: There is a very big Halachik difference between a woman that had an affair and a woman that was raped.

Comment: @yechezkel Not much in this case. They are both prohibited to their husbands.

Comment: Right. But while I can see a legitimate reason to deny her of תשמיש if she had an affair, a woman that was raped should be able to demand to be divorced if her husband is not planning on being with her.

Comment: @yechezkel The question wasn't about suing for divorce.