# Status of a Cohen Who Intermarries

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, intermarriage

What is the status of a cohen who intermarries?  He would not be able to eat Trumah, but does he continue to receive the first aliyah, and can he duchan (assuming he observes all other mitzvot)?

Comment: I think all his cohen privileges are suspended until he gets rid of his wife. He still has to avoid corpses. This is also technically true of a cohen who is merely not observant but many are lenient.

Comment: In theory I would imagine @ClintEastwood is right; in practice, though, I have seen such kohanim indeed receive the first aliyah. Not clear whether this was a mistake or done for some other reason, such as not to embarrass him

Answer (score 1):

A Kohein who marries a woman who is forbidden to him because he is a Kohein or a Kohein who defiles himself with corpse-related impurity does not bless the people and does not get any of the special privileges of being a Kohein (eg. called to the Torah first) until he stops doing the forbidden action and accepts to never do it again. ([Shulchan Aruch OC 128:40-41](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%97#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.9E))

A Kohein is forbidden to marry a non-Jew as a [Zonah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22496/759) (Rambam [Issurei Biah 17:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5117.htm#4)) so it would seem an intermarried Kohein loses all his priveleges.

Comment: Thank you.  However, is merely have relations with the non-jew considered marriage, halachically, if the relationship would otherwise be forbidden?  Your sources relate to marrying a grusha, who would presumably be jewish.

Comment: @cmose I'm not sure what your asking. The Rambam I linked to shows it's a violation of a Priestly prohibition. That should be enough to warrant not honoring him.

Comment: The source you quoted dealt with a grusha, and if he divorces her, his status returns.  My original question related to a civil marriage, but I'm not sure that it is a halachic one...so if stops having relations, then does his status return?

Comment: @cmose He needs to divorce (where applicable) and also "accept[] never [to] do it again", in this case, in the form of a public vow prohibiting anew to himself all the women he was forbidden to already.