# Are there any organizations or support groups that help older, unmarried Kohanim?

Tags: marriage, kohen-priest, age, organizations

Since a [Kohen is limited](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22495/prohibition-of-a-kohen-marrying-a-zonah) in their options for marrying, many older (35 years or more, possibly earlier) Kohanim have a very limited pool of marriage possibilities. This is especially true of a Kohain who becomes religious later in life, where the remaining possibilities are likely further limited by personal compatibility issues.

Regarding the issue of Agunos there are [many organizations](http://mmm1914.dulles19-verio.com/jwiorg/directory/agunot.htm) that seek to help make it possible for the woman to remarry and to aid them during the period that they can't. Are there any such organizations or support networks for older Kohanim?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.jewishdatingandmarriage.com/matchlist.html

Matchmakers Name: Mazel Tov Singles, Nosson Tuttle, Director.
 City: Monsey area 
 Telephone: 914-356-2590
 Email: ntuttle@photon.poly.edu
 Clients Ages:
 Clients Background: 
 Additional Details: Good resource for kohanim and women who can marry kohanim.