# Child of a Levi and an Egyptian convert

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, levites-leviyim

[From my comment here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90465/levi-marries-a-ger-does-the-son-inherit-levi-status#comment293090_90465)

If a Levi illegally marries an Egyptian or Edomi convert, what's the status of their children?

- They're second generation Egyptians, so they can't marry most Jews.  (But *their* kids will be allowed to.)
- Can they receive maaser?
- Can the boys serve as Leviyim?

Note that these people are *not* mamzeirim because the marriage doesn't carry kareis.  The case of a Levi marrying a mamzer is similar to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16580/11532) and addressed by some aspects of the answers and comments there.

Comment: From first glance he is a regular levi

Comment: As the linked question you commented on says, there are no restrictions on Levi lineage. I agree with kouty though it's probably hard to prove.

Comment: @kouty except that he can't marry most people.  I agree that's probably right, but it's an odd combination.

Comment: See Gittin 59b on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

See Rashi Yevamot 78a

> להם הלך אחר פסולן - תרי להם כתיבי ומשמע הלך אחריהם דאם נטמעו בכשרים כגון מצרי שנשא ישראלית וישראל שנשא מצרית הלך אחריהן והולד פסול עד דור שלישי: ‏

Mitsri who marry Israelite woman or Israel who marry an Egyptian woman, the offspring is pasul to go in Kahal up to the third gerenation. There are kiddushin and there is Avera the newborn takes the status of the pasul.

For Mitsri of first generation and Mitsrit of second generation, there is a Machloket Amorayim in Kiddushin 67a. The rule is that the count follows the more pasul. In our example the newborn will be a second generation and not a third.

So for a Levi also that is an Avera. This Halacha is strange because even if one of the father is not a convert generally the child is not a convert. Even for Cohanim, the son of a Cohen with a convert is a Chalal. And here the son has a status of mitsri. May be that regards only the count to reach the Heyter Bekahal. But from the pshat Hapashut of the Gemara, it seems that the child is a Mitsri simply. So he cannot get Maaser. He has a status of convert. Please if I'm wrong send me a comment.

Comment: Yes I understand he's not allowed to marry her, and I understand the child is a second generation mitzri for marriage purposes.  But can (s)he get maaser?  Can he sing in the Beis Hamikdash?