# What is the punishment for a Jewish non-married woman who has relations with a non-Jewish man?

Tags: gentiles, reward-punishment, sexuality

I have heard that the punishment is that she will forever be Zonah but I have no sources

Comment: Every non-Jew is forever a Zonah no matter what they do https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22496/759

Comment: @DoubleAA: Is it more accurate to say that since non-Jews lack a chezqas kashrus, there is no way to avoid applying the dinim of zonah to every nakhriyah. Because, who knows? Not that they are zonot, or we assume they are zonot, but we have no way of assuming they aren't.

(BTW, the woman in the OP is Jewish. So, not clear on the applicability of what reply to the question.)

Comment: @Micah No, that is not more accurate. Even a convert below 3 when we can know they have never Halachically had sex is a Zonah.

Comment: The question is regarding a Jewish woman who has relations with a non-Jewish man is considered a Zonah since she can never be considered married.

Comment: Theoretical punishment -- maybe lashes. *Consequence* is that she can't marry a kohen. The latter isn't a punishment, and applies even if she was raped.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

The relevant source is [Mishneh Torah, Issurei Biah 18:2-3](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960666/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Eighteen.htm#v2) (and from there in [Shulchan Aruch, Even Haezer 6:8](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7513)), that indeed such relations render her a zonah, thus making her forbidden to marry a kohen. (To be sure, as Shalom noted in comments, that's a consequence, not a punishment, and it applies even if she was raped.)

As for actual punishments: if it was in a marital relationship (and with her consent), then Rambam [ibid. 12:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960660/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Twelve.htm#v1) states that she's liable to lashes by biblical law, although Shulchan Aruch [ibid. 16:1](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7541) cites a dissenting opinion. If it was a casual relationship (and again, she consented to it), then I'm not sure: Rambam and Shulchan Aruch there say that a Jewish man who has such relations with a non-Jewish woman is subject to lashes by rabbinical law, but they don't say anything about the converse case.