If a female kohenet is considered a zonah would it impact her ability to marry a male kohen?
I'm seeing very conflicting opinions on this issue, so I thought to ask.

I don't see anything here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22496/759 about being a kohenet

It doesn't matter if the woman in question is a kohenet or not, a Zonah from any lineage (Kohen, Levi, Yisrael) is not allowed to be married to a Kohen.
See Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer 6:1

כהן אסור מן התורה בגרושה זונה וחללה
A priest is forbidden from the Torah to marry a divorced woman, a harlot, or a challalah (a woman of invalid priestly lineage)


??? Your source doesn't say that

@DoubleAA The shulchan aruch doesn't differentiate, isn't that proof enough

If you checked the whole shulchan aruch that'd be a decent proof. Checking all commentaries and responsa would be even better. But what you wrote in this post doesn't even make sense
